# IE 11 image load issue (loading on refresh)

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer

I have an issue with image loading in IE 11. I am displaying coupons (in RABAT theme) in a page. But some of the thumbnails are not uploading. If I just refresh page all thumbnail images displayed without any issue.
My IE version is 11.0.9600.17959 .
The main issue is that some of images are not loading first time (a red cross image appears instead) and on refresh image just appears.
If I long click on an image and click show Pictures, it shows image.
Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Thanks
Abhishek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem by reloading broken images if not loaded properly in first attempt. 
Here is the git repository location and JS site link where this code is located:

https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded
http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/

Add this js code in your page :

```
var imgLoading = ImagesLoaded(document); imgLoading.done(function () { console.log('All images loaded successfully'); console.log('Images: ', this.images); }); imgLoading.fail(function () { console.error('One or more images have failed to load'); console.log('Proper images: ', this.proper); console.log('Broken images: ', this.broken); }); imgLoading.always(function () { if (this.isDone) { console.log('All images loaded successfully'); } if (this.isFailed) { console.error('One or more images have failed to load'); } console.log('Proper images: ', this.proper); console.log('Broken images: ', this.broken); } ); imgLoading.progress(function (img, isBroken) { console.log('This image has finished with loading:', img); console.log('The image is ' + (isBroken ? 'broken' : 'properly loaded')); if (isBroken){ img.src = img.src+"?time=" + new Date(); } // Current state of loading console.log('Pending images:', this.pending); console.log('Loaded images:', this.loaded); console.log('Proper: ', this.proper); console.log('Broken: ', this.broken); } );
```

Main method is imgLoading.progress(function (img, isBroken).

A simple logic is added to this method to reload image if broken, by added a time stamp to it, just to force reload image so that browser thinks of it as a new URL and goes to server to load it instead of from Cache. Like this:

```
if (isBroken){ img.src = img.src+"?time=" + new Date(); }
```

And that is it. Now image will be reloaded at least once if broken.